# How to insert an imageView to a tableView, so that the image view scrolls as I scroll the tableview

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

How to insert an imageView to a tableView, so that the image view scrolls as I scroll the tableview?
I added a imageview to tableview using the method tableview.addsubview, but when I scroll the tableview, the image view is floating. It will not move as I scroll these cells. Otherwise, the image is created by UIGraphics.

```
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
tableview.addSubview(UIImageView(image: image))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hc3r.jpg)

The image is about all cells. There are some lines in the image. Each line is from the point of last label in cell to the point of next label in next cell. So, I hope that the image is cover all cells.

Comment: Can't you add the ImageView to a cell ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the image to a cell, not to the tableview. If you add it to the tableview it will float because you are actually scrolling the Cells and not the tableview itself.

So in your tableView delegate method where you are constructing your cells you should add the imageview.

Comment: The image is about all cells. There are some lines in the image. Each line is from the point of last label in cell to  the point of next label in next cell. So, I hope that the image is cover all cells. Thanks.